# How to use the same key and same colours for different datasets with gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am plotting:

```
p " file1" u ($2-0.25):8:(.2) every ::1::568, "file2" u ($2):8:(.2) every ::568::1136, "file3" u ($2+0.25):8:(.2) every ::1137::1705
```

It produces three different keys and three different colour lines. However, I would also like to have the three of them using the same colour and the same legend (key). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `title` and `linecolor` (or `fill`) for each datafile. To remove the legend entry, use `notitle`.

```
plot sin(x), cos(x) linecolor 1 notitle
```